# Verificar appserver disponível via script

Tags: progress-4gl

Tenho uma script em openedge que envia por api um cadastro de produto para uma aplicação, porém a request só aceita um objeto por vez, por isso preciso rodar dentro de um foreach da tabela de itens e por isso ele ocupa todas os appserver e consequentemente barra os processos.

Queria saber se é possível de alguma maneira, verificar por script se existe appserver disponível para utilizar.

Answer (score -2):

You could run asbman and "screen scrape" the output. Something along these lines:

asbman -query -i apsrvName | grep "available servers"

Você pode executar o asbman e "raspar a tela" da saída. Algo nessa linha:

asbman -query -i apsrvName | grep "servidores disponíveis"